# How can I update the next row - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I’m new using Google sheets, and I have the following situation:

I have an external application and once a day it generates a report.
 I’m getting the report data(via JSON), and importing it in the Google sheets. 
I want to update the data from the next day in a new row. 
Right now, I implemented the script to import a Json but, the data are always updating the same row.
How can I update the next row, after import the new data?

Comment: share your json script

Comment: How about sheet.getLastRow()+1 or sheet.appendRow().  They're in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks guys it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the JSON data into a variant, and then use [`.appendRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) method on the [`Sheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) object.

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var ws = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var appd = wscl.appendRow([var, var, var]);
```